# What are the limitations of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

The Generalized uncertainty principle is the general form of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. So what limitations of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle are covered in the modified principle ?

Comment: Just to be sure everybody is on the same page, what's your definitions of generalized HUP and modified HUP?

Comment: Actually I haven't read generalized uncertainty principle yet. And by modified HUP i meant GUP only. So, i just want to know that why there was a need for a general principle.

Answer (score -1):

The Heisenberg uncertainty principle, as typically defined, is a relation specifically between $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p$. The generalized version allows you to find relations between any other operators, e.g relations for angular momenta & position, more abstract operators, etc.

Comment: Actually the Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle isn't just restricted to momentum and position. It also involves other operators too.

Comment: Usually when people cite just "HUP" they are referring to the position/momentum relation, and if they are referring to other relations they will mention "HUP for ___" or include the word "general" or "generalized" in their description. Really it's just a matter of definition and no one really cares, but I thought that this was what your question was asking.

Answer (score -1):

In general, the uncertainty principle is a statement claiming that the number of bits of information, that can ever be recovered from any set of observations of an entity, must be greater than or equal to 1 bit. It is the limiting case of Shannon's Capacity Theorem (Information Theory).
See: http://vixra.org/pdf/1609.0129v1.pdf, page 5

Comment: Interesting. Is this theory of yours generally accepted part of mainstream (peer reviewed) physics, or does it exist only in self-published form?